# Customize title template based on page

Tags: 8, theming

I know I can customize the template by overriding `page-title.html.twig`
but I'm looking for a way to have more than one title template. in my case, the suggested name form my path is  `page__manage__customer_list` So I tried to override it with `page--manage--customer-list-title.html.twig`. 
how is that possible to override the title template?

to make the question more generalize and could be useful for other guys that looking for similar circumstances this could be helpful.

**How can I override the title template based on content type or route?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add new templates to already existing using [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x)

Example of adding a content type:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_page_title_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $content_type = $node->bundle();
    $suggestions[] = 'page_title__' . $content_type;
  }
}
```

Then use **page-title--content-type.html.twig**

---

You could use `$node->id();` if content type is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks for @No Sssweat give a clue to me. her solution works for content types only. **but for Taxonomy page and General pages ( custom pages you've created by custom route like me) the following snippet will work charmingly:**

on `YOURTHEMENAME.theme` file

```
use \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function YOURTHEMENAME_theme_suggestions_page_title_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  $path_args = explode('/', trim(\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath(), '/'));
  $suggestions = theme_get_suggestions($path_args, 'page_title');

  if ($tid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term')) {
    $term = Term::load($tid);
    $vid = $term->vid->getValue();
    $suggestions[] = 'page_title__taxonomy__vocabulary__' . $vid[0]['target_id'];
  }

  elseif ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $content_type = $node->bundle();
    $suggestions[] = 'page_title__' . $content_type;
  }
 // ksm($suggestions);
}
```

then it works for all pages.

**page-title--CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME.html.twig** (sample for article content type : **page-title--article.html.twig**

**page_title__taxonomy__vocabulary__VOCABULARY_MACHINE_NAME.html.twig** ( sample for tags vocabulary is : **page_title__taxonomy__vocabulary__tags.html.twig**

Ref : [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.6.x)